# Smoothing out microcontroller audio for Sphinx library

Tags: java, c, esp32

Good morning folks, I am trying to send audio data from a microphone attached to an ESP32 board over wifi to my desktop running some Java code. if I run the audio data using Java's AudioSystems library its a bit staticy but is legible. switching to use the Sphinx-4 library which converts audio to text it only sometimes recognizes the words.

This is the first time I've had to mess with raw audio data so it may not even be possible since the board can only read up to 12 bit signals which means converting a 16 bit, every single 12 bit value maps at 15 16bit values. it could also be due to the roughly 115 microsecond delay to down sample to 16kHz

How can I smooth out the audio playback enough that it can be easily recognized by the Sphinx4 library? The current implementation has very small breaks and some noise that I think is throwing it off

**ESP32 Code:**

```
BUFFERMAX = 8000
ONE_SECOND = 1000000
int writeBuffer[BUFFERMAX];
void writeAudio(){
  for(int i=0; i< BUFFERMAX;i=i+1){

  //data read in is 12 bits so I mapped the value to 16 bits ( 2 bytes)
  sensorValue = (map(analogRead(sensorPin), 0, 4096, -32000, 32000));

  //none to minimal sound is around -7000 so try to zero out additional noise with average
  int prevAvg = avg;
  avg = (avg + sensorValue)/2;
  sensorValue = (abs(prevAvg) + sensorValue);
  if(abs(sensorValue) < 1000){sensorValue = 0;}

  writeBuffer[i] = ((sensorValue));
  // delay so that 8000 INTs (16000 bytes) takes one second to record
  delayMicroseconds(delayMicro);
}
client.write((byte*)writeBuffer, sizeof(writeBuffer));
```

**Java Sphinx:**

```
StreamSpeechRecognizer recognizer = new StreamSpeechRecognizer(configuration);
// Start recognition process pruning previously cached data.

recognizer.startRecognition(socket.getInputStream() );

System.out.print("awaiting command...");
SpeechResult result = recognizer.getResult();
System.out.println(result.getHypothesis().toLowerCase());
```

**Java play audio:**

```
private static void init() throws LineUnavailableException {
    //  specifying the audio format
    AudioFormat _format = new AudioFormat(16000.F,// Sample Rate
            16,     // Size of SampleBits
            1,      // Number of Channels
            true,   // Is Signed?
            false   // Is Big Endian?
    );

    //  creating the DataLine Info for the speaker format
    DataLine.Info speakerInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, _format);

    //  getting the mixer for the speaker
    _speaker = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(speakerInfo);
    _speaker.open(_format);
}


_streamIn = socket.getInputStream();

_speaker.start();

byte[] data = new byte[16000];
System.out.println("Waiting for data...");
while (_running) {
    long start = new Date().getTime();

    //  checking if the data is available to speak
    if (_streamIn.available() <= 0)
        continue;   //  data not available so continue back to start of loop

    //  count of the data bytes read
    int readCount= _streamIn.read(data, 0, data.length);

    if(readCount > 0 && (readCount%2) == 0){
        System.out.println(readCount);
        _speaker.write(data, 0, readCount);
        readCount=0;
    }
    System.out.println("Time: " + (new Date().getTime() - start));
}
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: Sorry, edited the question. Basically i want to smooth out the audio enough that the Sphinx4 library can recognize voice better. the current implementation has very small breaks and some noise that I think is throwing it off

Comment: Where are the breaks, in the raw recorded data, or later? And the noise, is it already in this raw data, too?

Comment: I believe so, for the breaks its basically like very small skips which I'm pretty sure is from the microsecond delays  that im using to essentially down sample the audio. the noise is either outliers from the average or because the 16kHz sample rate is slightly too fast which I found does create some noise on the speakers.

Comment: Can you provide some example audio?

Comment: I would recommend using a digital mic with the ESP32. You can find cheap MEMS I2S mics that are easy to hook up. You should then be able to get excellent audio quality, as good as a modern mobile phone or internal laptop mic

Comment: Even with an analog mic like now you should really use the built-in audio capture pheripheral in the ESP32 It will give you samples without any jitter, and without taking up the entire CPU as your current approach.

Comment: @jonnor a co-worker sent me this the other day, is it similar to what you mean? [ESP32-I2S-Mems](https://github.com/maspetsberger/esp32-i2s-mems). Also currently I'm using Adafruit-max9814 which I think is a digital mic but has a conversion built in. (I could be wrong I'm still pretty new to this stuff)

Comment: Yes like that repo. What you have now is an analog mic with autogain preamplifier.